# Using "git add ." (or abusing it)

Tags: git

My understanding is that `git add .` will add all files in the directory to the repository.

Then normally, if you edit a file, you will `git add file.name` just that file to bring it to the staging area.

I'm wondering if there is anything wrong with just doing `git add .` again at this point, to add all files you've modified to the staging area? Obviously, this runs `git add` on every file, even those that have not changed, is this bad? I'm guessing it is not an issue, but wanted to check here.

Of course, I also know that I can do `git commit -a` but I'm not sure if this is technically the same as doing `git add .` followed by `git commit` or if it is smart enough to just `add` specific files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also know that I can do `git commit -a` but I'm not sure if this is
>   technically the same as doing `git add .` followed by `git commit` or if
>   it is smart enough to just add specific files.

`git commit -a` isn't quite the same as saying `git add . ; git commit`.

`git help commit` would tell you:

```
   -a, --all
       Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been
       modified and deleted, but new files you have not told git about are
       not affected.
```

That said, the two would behave the same *if* you haven't added new files.

Doing `git add foo` repeatedly wouldn't cause any side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

`git add .` doesn't remove files that have been deleted, to be more specific, it is the same as:

```
git add --no-all .
```

What you probably want is to update only the files that changed.

```
git add --update .
```

In Git 2.0, `git add .` will change to the current `git add --all .`, so it would remove files that have been deleted, and will add all files not present before, so you probably should start using `--update` instead.

Answer (score 0):

git `add .` won't remove any files that were deleted since the last commit.
 If you're deleting files, I'd use git rm  so that git is informed of the removed file, and you don't forget to make sure git knows it was deleted. As mentioned in another comment, git `commit -a` will notice files that have been deleted.

I advise you to make a git status after git add .

I use every time `add .` but is a good way to see what you put inside this add. For me anything is wrong with git `add .`

The only thing is if you see after git status some files that you don't want to push you can select the files only that you want to put online.

Usually after some editing of code is advised to make a push with some files, isnpt a good way to make a big push with a lot of files because if you work in team some of these files can overwrite  o make some merge inside your branch